# How to create a csv file with scalars and array? python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, csv

So I'm trying to create a csv file where, for example, 2 of the 3 columns would have a scalar value and the third would have an array. Basically the problem it's that using Pandas DataFrame method, the created csv file would have all the rows from the first 2 columns, filled with the scalar values of those columns, something like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 50 | 2304 |
| 2 | 50 | 5434 |
| 2 | 50 | 6788 |
| ... | ... | ... |

where the desirable result would be :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 50 | 2304 |
|  |  | 5434 |
|  |  | 6788 |
|  |  | ... |

Is there any easy/understandable way to do this? ( I'm still learning Python )

Thanks a lot for the attention :)

Comment: Any particular reason you need to save to a CSV file? CSV files are not well suited to writing data of the structure you describe. It would be more natural to use a format like JSON, where data does not have to be tabular.

Comment: Uh.. I might just have to try it out :D Thanks for the tip!